# Docker use authenticated call to git

Tags: git, docker, authentication, github, wget

Im having docker image which needs to read data from github.mycompany.com
I was able to do it currently and it works however now we need to switch the security as 
**anonymous/unauthenticated access to git company is deprecated**,
which option do I've to still use it as authenticated.

Currently this is my call which is **working** as **anonymous/unauthenticated**

`wget https://github.mycompoany.corp/raw/dng/dekpos/master/Key.gpg -O- | apt-key add - && \`

What should I do to make it authenticated ?

There is an option to use wget with `wget http://url --user=<user> --password=<password>` 
But not sure how to create this user and password on github side, or any other way with some token which I need to provide?

We are using GitHub for enterprises

I've those option in the settings for this specific repo, what should I use?

[image]

Comment: Are you using some software on top of git there, such as GitLab?

Comment: @AMoustache - no we are using github corporate

Comment: Are you running this as part of your build, or does your application need live access to the repositories as it's running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through ssh with a ssh key.

On github : add an ssh key to an account. Check with your team how they want to manage access to the company's github : it could be your account, or an account dedicated for testing/QA.

Option 1 : the key would be dedicated to accessing the repo from this docker image ; put the corresponding private key straight in the docker image, and access the repo on github.

Option 2 : if this image is going to run on your company's infra, you could setup a mirror somewhere on your infra (using that authenticated ssh access), and target this mirror from your docker image.

---

Github provides all the information necessary to deploy ssh keys : [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/) and [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

the basics are :

- you generate a private/public pair **on your computer** (the private part should never be knowned by github),
- you copy the *public* part to github,
- you use the private part from the correct machine.

Comment: Thanks, please see my update with the picture, for option 1 , how should I get the private key?

Comment: Should I use the deploy key option for my case?

Comment: 1+ The name is `deploy...` :) does it will provide and read access to the repo ? if there is any example with docker it will be great.